# Check CRLF at the end of every file

Tags: powershell

I have got about 500 txt files, some of them have got "CRLF" and some not.

How can I check files with last line ending by "CRLF", and if not, add "CRLF".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$folder = "\\FolderWith\TextFiles" 
dir $folder -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
  try {
    $content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.Fullname)
    if($content -notmatch '(?<=\r\n)\z')
    {
       Add-Content -Value ([environment]::newline) -Path $_.fullname
    } 
  }
  catch {}
}
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I want! And thanks also to Chard

Comment: This script add two new lines at the end of the file. Either use `Add-Content -Value ([environment]::newline) -Path $_.fullname -NoNewline` or simply `Add-Content -Value "" -Path $_.fullname`