# Check if the last line in a file is empty in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to add some content to a file in a new line.
But `add-content` appends a string to last line if there is no new line symbol at the end.

E.g. if I want to add `AAA` string and if I have a file `file1.txt`

```
my last line(last cursor position here)
```

the result will be

```
my last lineAAA
```

On the other hand, if I use `file2.txt`

```
my last line
(last cursor position here)
```

the command will result in

```
my last line
AAA
```

So I need to check if the last line is empty or not. If it's not empty I will just add `n symbol to the string.

But if I run the commands

```
$lastLine = get-content $filename -Tail 1
if($lastLine.Length -ne 0) { ... }
```

it will always return me a length of not empty string even if my last line contains no symbols.
How can I check if my last line is empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could opt to start adding newlines to the file and for the **first line to add** do

```
$file      = 'D:\Test\Blah.txt'
$firstLine = 'AAA'
Add-Content -Path $file -Value ("{0}`r`n{1}" -f (Get-Content -Path $file -Raw).TrimEnd(), $firstLine)
```

After that first line, you can simply keep using `Add-Content` which always appends an newline (unless you tell it not to do that with switch `-NoNewline`).

---

Seeing your comment, you can test the length of the last line like this:

```
$file = 'D:\Test\Blah.txt'
$lastLine = ((Get-Content -Path $file -Raw) -split '\r?\n')[-1]
# $lastLine.Length --> 0
if($lastLine.Length -ne 0) { ... }
```

<sup>The `-Raw` switch tells Get-Content to read the file as a whole in a single string. Split this string into separate lines with  `-split '\r?\n'` and you'll get an array, **including** the last empty line</sup>

Comment: The problem is that  this file can be edited in both ways: manually and using `add-content`. So after manual editing the issue can still be present.

Answer (score 2):

When you use "Get-Content -Tail 1", it will always recover the last "non empty" line.

```
# -----------------
# Your method returns the same line even if the file contains an empty line at the end of the file
# -----------------
$lastEmptyLine = Get-Content "test_EmptyLine.txt" -Tail 1
$lastNonEmptyLine = Get-Content "test_NonEmptyLine.txt" -Tail 1

($lastEmptyLine -match '(?<=\r\n)\z')
#False
($lastNonEmptyLine -match '(?<=\r\n)\z')
#False
```

So if you want to keep the "Test" method (and not simply use Add-Content) you could use the following method :

```
# -----------------
# This method can tell you if a file finishes by an empty line or not
# -----------------
$contentWithEmptyLine = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("test_EmptyLine.txt")
$contentWithoutEmptyLine = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("test_NonEmptyLine.txt")

($contentWithEmptyLine -match '(?<=\r\n)\z')
#True
($contentWithoutEmptyLine -match '(?<=\r\n)\z')
#False

# -----------------
# You can also use Get-Content with Raw option
# -----------------
$rawContentWithEmptyLine = Get-Content "test_EmptyLine.txt" -Raw
$rawContentWithoutEmptyLine = Get-Content "test_NonEmptyLine.txt" -Raw

($rawContentWithEmptyLine -match '(?<=\r\n)\z')
#True
($rawContentWithoutEmptyLine -match '(?<=\r\n)\z')
#False
```

> -Raw **Ignores newline characters** and returns the entire contents of a file in one string **with the newlines preserved**. By default, newline
> characters in a file are used as delimiters to separate the input into
> an array of strings. This parameter was introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

### References :

[Get-Content (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7)

[Check CRLF at the end of every file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137840/check-crlf-at-the-end-of-every-file)

[about_Comparison_Operators - PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)

[Regular expression - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I chose previous answer because he was earlier. 
But your solution is very nice!